Issues trying to consume Kafka messages on kubernetes using KRaft
I'm using docker desktop running Kubernetes.
I'm setting up my environment using the next configuration:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: kafka-network
spec:
  ingress:
    - from:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              network/kafka-network: "true"
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      network/kafka-network: "true"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: kafka-controller
  name: kafka-controller
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: kafka-controller
    run: kafka-controller
  ports:
    - name: internal
      port: 9093
      targetPort: 9093
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka-controller
spec:
  serviceName: kafka-controller
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-controller
      run: kafka-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        network/kafka-network: "true"
        app: kafka-controller
        run: kafka-controller
    spec:
      hostname: kafka-controller
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      enableServiceLinks: false
      containers:
        - name: kafka-controller
          image: apache/kafka:3.9.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9093
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_OPTS
              value: "-Djavax.net.debug=all"
            - name: KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL
              value: debug
            - name: KAFKA_NODE_ID
              value: "0"
            - name: KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES
              value: "controller"
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
              value: "CONTROLLER://:9093"
            - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
              value: "PLAINTEXT"
            - name: KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES
              value: "CONTROLLER"
            - name: KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS
              value: "0@kafka-controller-0.kafka-controller.default.svc.cluster.local:9093"
            - name: KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS
              value: "0"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: kafka-broker
  name: kafka-broker
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: kafka-broker
    run: kafka-broker
  ports:
    - name: internal
      port: 29092
      targetPort: 29092
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka-broker
spec:
  serviceName: kafka-broker
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-broker
      run: kafka-broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        network/kafka-network: "true"
        app: kafka-broker
        run: kafka-broker
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      enableServiceLinks: false
      hostname: kafka-broker
      containers:
        - name: kafka-broker
          image: apache/kafka:3.9.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 29092
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_OPTS
              value: "-Djavax.net.debug=all"
            - name: KAFKA_NODE_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES
              value: "broker"
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: "PLAINTEXT://kafka-broker-0.kafka-broker.default.svc.cluster.local:29092"
            - name: KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE
              value: "true"
            - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
              value: "PLAINTEXT"
            - name: KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES
              value: "CONTROLLER"
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
              value: "PLAINTEXT://:29092"
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
              value: "PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT"
            - name: KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS
              value: "0@kafka-controller-0.kafka-controller.default.svc.cluster.local:9093"
            - name: KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS
              value: "0"

After initialize the services with the command kubectl apply -f kafka.yml, I see no errors into the logs. If I get into one of the pods:
I can create topics using the command:
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server=kafka-broker:29092 --topic event_topic --partitions 2
I can describe the created topic with:
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server=kafka-broker:29092 --describe --topic event_topic
I can publish new messages into the topic using:
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-broker:29092 --topic event_topic
And validate the message is available into the kafka logs:
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --deep-iteration --print-data-log --files /tmp/kafka-logs/event_topic-0/00000000000000000000.log
Nevertheless, I'm unable to consume messages from the topic:
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic event_topic --from-beginning --group=c7abf8f3-6ec1-4798-aff5-feeee0886838 --bootstrap-server kafka-broker:29092
Deploying the services using docker-compose appears to work just fine, so, probably... am I misconfiguring something?
I tried so far:

Remove the group for the consumer
Use "bootstrap-server" as "kafka-broker-0.kafka-broker.default.svc.cluster.local:29092"
Use "bootstrap-server" as "kafka-broker-0:29092"

None of them appear to produce an error, but no message is showing up into the consumer.
The only log I'm getting is a constant INFO message into the broker "INFO Sent auto-creation request for Set(__consumer_offsets) to the active controller. (kafka.server.DefaultAutoTopicCreationManager)" as far as I can tell, this is just the consumer offset update.
No other log messages are present into the controller.
Thank you in advance for your help.
